# Azure websites Static IP

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying to find an answer but the documentation that i found is not very clear. 
Whenever i create a azure-website in a **STANDARD** plan the IP that i get is static? or, do i need to create a self-signed cert and bind it to the IP like discussed in the following link: [Azure Website Reserved IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374448/azure-website-reserved-ip)

(The goal is to know if i can use the IP as a A record in my provider)

Thankful for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/05/05/how-to-get-a-static-ip-address-for-your-microsoft-azure-web-site.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sofar, the only solution I could think of to solve this is to make use of a proxy server.
Setup a VM with a Proxy server on it (nginx, iis with arr/urlrewrite/reverse proxy). The VM will have the static IP, and pass through all incoming requests to proper Azure function / webjob / app.
Any better solutions are welcome. ASE is to expensive to be considered for many cases.